# NameError: name 'a' is not defined... gives this error even after I have converted variable to global

Tags: python

I'm getting this error and am not able to find any proper reason or solution it

```
def change_a():
    global a
    for i in ['O','X']:
        if not(i==a):
            a=i
            break
```

The purpose of this code is to switch between X and O.

the output I get is:

```
NameError: name 'a' is not defined.
```

I'm running this in Python 3.9.0

Comment: Give `a` a value outside the function.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Global variable is not defined - Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28237966/global-variable-is-not-defined-python)

Answer (score 1):

At the time of the comparison `(i==a)` the variable `a` is not yet defined. Therefore, you need to provide `a` with a value before that.
In addition, as Shannarra mentioned, you can switch the variable between the two characters:

```
a = 'X'

def change_a():
    global a
    a = 'O' if a == 'X' else 'O'
    print(a)
change_a()
```

Output:

```
O
```

Also, note that using global variables is considered bad practice as they enable functions to have hidden (non-obvious, surprising, hard to detect and diagnose) side effects, leading to an increase in complexity, potentially leading to spaghetti code.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to just switch the variable between those two characters you can:

```py
a = 'O' if a == 'X' else 'X'
```

No need for the function, the loop or the global variable.